# Reshaping and summarizing data over irregular intervals

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
 person surveyDate value
      a       2006    35
      a       2009    44
      b       2005    24
      b       2007    38
      c       2006    51
      c       2007    52
      c       2009    49
```

...and I want to reshape it into something like the following:

```
person dateDiff valueDiff
     a        3         9
     b        2        14
     c        3        -2
```

...where dateDiff is the difference between the earliest and the latest surveyDate for each person, and valueDiff is the difference between the earliest and latest value for each person. Note that some people are surveyed more than others and the time between surveys varies as well.

I've been trying to do this with `data.table` (and `melt`/`dcast`) but trying to assign new column values using `:=` in `j` has got me completely stumped. Other methods are welcome. Speed is not a big concern since the dataset isn't gigantic.

Comment: `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(x[c(1, .N)])), by = person]` ?

Comment: Might as well post that, @David . To me, `x[.N]-x[1]` looks more natural and won't bug out if `.N==1`. Or even `DF[, .SD[.N] - .SD[1], by = person]`

Comment: @Frank lol, I like that last one. Maybe you should post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
DT[, .SD[.N] - .SD[1], by = person]

#    person surveyDate value
# 1:      a          3     9
# 2:      b          2    14
# 3:      c          3    -2
```

If a group has only `.N==1` observations, the diffs will be shown as zero.

Alternately, ...

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[.N]-x[1]), by = person]
```

which the OP reports is much faster.

Comment: `.SD[.N] - .SD[1]` works fine, and I did mention that speed isn't a big concern in my question, but your initial suggestion in the comments above to use `lapply(.SD, function(x) x[.N]-x[1])` is _much_ faster--it takes roughly 1/20th of the time on my dataset. Regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super great at summarise in dplyr yet, but here's a clunky answer:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

person <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c')
surveyDate <- c(2006, 2009, 2005, 2007, 2006, 2007, 2009)
value <- c(35, 44, 24, 38, 51, 52, 49)

df <- data.frame(person, surveyDate, value)

value_diff <- function(surveyDate, value) {
    group_df <- data.frame(surveyDate, value)
    earliest_value <- group_df %>% 
        arrange(surveyDate) %>% 
        slice(1) %>% 
        extract2(2)
    latest_value <- group_df %>% 
        arrange(desc(surveyDate)) %>% 
        slice(1) %>% 
        extract2(2)
    diff <- latest_value - earliest_value
}

df %>% 
    group_by(person) %>% 
    summarise(dateDiff = max(surveyDate) -min(surveyDate), 
              valueDiff = value_diff(surveyDate, value))
```

Comment: `df %>% arrange(surveyDate) %>% group_by(person) %>% summarise_each(funs(.[n()]-.[1]))`?